# JOIN on DATEPART month and year is causing extra rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, cartesian-product, datepart

I have two tables that contain a date field. This date field is one of the JOIN causes that I would like to implement, but I only want to JOIN on the month and year, not the day. The # of records about triple when I attempt to do so. I'm guessing there is something wrong with my query? Or is this even possible?  I'm using Postgres

```
SELECT a.load_date , a.mandt, a.vbeln,a.posnr, a.matnr, b.tfed
FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b
ON date_part('month'::text, a.erdat) = date_part('month'::text, b.gdatu)
AND date_part('year'::text, a.erdat) = date_part('year'::text, b.gdatu)
```

EDIT  Here is my full code

```
 SELECT a.mandt, a.vbeln, 
   a.erdat, a.erzet, a.ernam, a.angdt, a.audat, a.vbtyp, a.trvog, 
   a.auart, a.submi, a.lifsk, a.faksk, a.netwr, a.waerk, a.vkorg, a.vtweg, a.spart, 
   a.vkgrp, a.vkbur, a.knumv, a.vdatu, a.vprgr, a.kalsm, a.vsbed, a.fkara, a.awahr, 
   a.bstnk, a.bstdk, a.telf1, a.kunnr, a.stafo, a.stwae, a.aedat, a.kvgr1,a.kvgr2, 
   a.kvgr3, a.kokrs, a.kkber, a.knkli, a.sbgrp, a.ctlpc, a.cmwae, a.cmfre, a.cmngv, 
   a.amtbl, a.hityp_pr, a.abrvw, a.vgbel, a.objnr, a.bukrs_vf, a.taxk1,a.xblnr, 
   a.vgtyp, a.abhod, a.abhov, a.stceg_l, a.landtx, a.fmbdat, a.vsnmr_v, a.handle, 
   a.yybcawv1, a.yybcawv2, a.yybcawv3, a.yyawv1dat, a.yyawv2dat, a.yybcawvc, 
   a.kvgr5, a.augru, a.autlf, a.bname, a.bnddt, a.bsark, a.cmnup, a.fiscalper,              
   a.fiscalyr, a.gwldt, a.ihrez, a.intind, a.intsum, a.rplnr, a.taxk2, a.yybabt, 
   a.yybemail, a.yybfax, a.yybname, a.yybphone, a.yyexporter, a.yypaypal_id, 
   a.yysd_projid, a.zone, a.zuonr, a.zz_campaign_id, a.zzedate, a.zzrev_cat_01, 
   a.zzrev_cat_02, a.zzrev_cat_03, a.zzrev_cat_04, a.zzrev_cat_05, a.zzrev_cat_06, 
   a.zzrev_cat_07, a.zzrev_cat_08, a.zzsdate, a.mahdt,
   CASE
        WHEN b.fcurr::text = 'USD'::text THEN a.netwr
        WHEN b.fcurr::text = 'JPY'::text AND b.kurst::text = 'M'::text THEN a.netwr * b.ukurs / 10::numeric
        WHEN b.fcurr::text = 'KRW'::text AND b.kurst::text = 'M'::text THEN a.netwr * b.ukurs / 10::numeric
        WHEN b.kurst::text = 'M'::text THEN a.netwr * b.ukurs
        ELSE a.netwr
    END AS net_value_trans_currency_netwr
FROM src.sap_vbak a
JOIN src.sap_tcurr b  
ON a.waerk::text = b.fcurr::text 
AND date_part('MONTH'::text, a.erdat::timestamp with time zone) = date_part('MONTH'::text, b.gdatu::timestamp with time zone)
AND date_part('YEAR'::text, a.erdat::timestamp with time zone) = date_part('YEAR'::text, b.gdatu::timestamp with time zone);
```

I'm attempting to get currency conversions based off of the dates (month and year only) in each of the tables. Some of the currency conversion are different ( the CASE statement for net_value_trans_currency_netwr field). I am wanting the net_value_trans_currency_netwr field to be a new row that displays the currency conversion in USD. The original table has over 5 million rows. After the joins I end up with way more rows. From what I gather I'm getting a full join. How would I be able to execute what I'm trying to do without the full join creating more than needed rows?

Comment: I'm not really surprised that you get more rows when you make the join condition less strict. But you should show us some sample data, the output and explain why that output is wrong.

Comment: you have to edit your join condition to a case statement if year = year then join on month. it eliminates duplicates by going to year by year. i suggest you to add one more where exists.

Comment: You need to group them somehow. Can't help without knowing more. Some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Well, the # of records in the table jump from 6,168,781 to 19,022,763 once the join is created. This is why I'm thinking that something is not right.

Comment: Here is the full code that I wrote that I am attempting to get to work:

Comment: Edited original question above ^

Comment: Does your currency table have multiple rows (with rates) for a single currency in a single month? (i.e. rate changes by day perhaps?)

Comment: It has multiple rows for a single currency (i.e. USD) in a single month. But it contains snapshots from multiple months, not daily changes.

Answer (score 2):

You get duplicate rows as you are INNER JOINING on the month and year which are not unique. This is causing a cross join e.g.

```
Example Rows with dates
   Date          Month    Year
1  01/01/2014    01       14
2  02/01/2014    01       14

Result of above join has 4 rows not 2!
1) Month from (1) Year from (1)
2) Month from (1) Year from (2)
3) Month from (2) Year from (1)
4) Month from (2) Year from (2)
```

If you want to avoid this you need something else to include in the join that makes each join unique! Adding the day may help but again if you have more than one date recorded on the same day you will get a duplicate. Have a think what else you could include on the join.

Comment: No probs. If you think it's useful, Select my post as having answered your query!

Comment: I have no other fields that are unique to use as join clauses. How would I be able to compare the month/year another way?

Comment: So from you updated query you have a list of Transactions in Table A (src.sap_vbak) and Currency in Table B (src.sap_tcurr). Is there anything in src.sap_vbak that could identify which currency is being used e.g. a Location column? If not, I'm presuming you want to get the correct currency for your transaction. How can you tell which currency applies to the transaction (i.e. which columns give us that information)? Without that info we aren't going to be able to progress this.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The fields that I currently have the join on, src.sap_vbak.waerk and src.sap_tcurr is the currency type. i.e. USD, or JPY.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`date_trunc()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) to simplify the query:

```
SELECT a.load_date, a.mandt, a.vbeln,a.posnr, a.matnr, b.tfed
FROM   tableA a
JOIN   tableB b ON date_trunc('month', a.erdat)
                 = date_trunc('month', b.gdatu);
```

Plus, you probably want to restrict the join further. This is a limited **cross join** resulting in a [**Cartesian product**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). If you have 3 rows for March 2014 in a `tableA` and 4 rows for March 2014 in a `tableB`, you already produce 12 rows in the result.

Comment: @user3329160: Of course it does, just simpler and faster. You need to define additional conditions which rows from `tableA` joins which row from `tableB`.

Comment: There's no other conditions that join the two tables together.

Comment: @user3329160: Then you have to reduce the number of rows per month to 1 on one of the two sides, in a subselect or CTE. With `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT ON` ... I don't have enough information to say more.